# How can I use various function in fullcalnedar?

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar

I want various functions in fullcalnedar. I used Selectable dates, and event add button. However, as a result, only the add button works well. The script is in html. Does the last script apply only? If that be so, how can I apply all the functions? This is an additional question, but if all functions are available, how should I implement the function of adding events by selecting a date? Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />

        <title>
            Drag-n-drop external events - Demos | FullCalendar
        </title>

        <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="ko.js"></script>
        <script src="main.js"></script>

        <script>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
                var Calendar = FullCalendar.Calendar;
                var Draggable = FullCalendar.Draggable;

                var containerEl = document.getElementById('external-events');
                var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
                var checkbox = document.getElementById('drop-remove');



                // initialize the calendar
                // -----------------------------------------------------------------

                var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
                    headerToolbar: {
                        left: 'prev,next today',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay',
                    },
                    editable: true, 
                    droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar
                    drop: function (info) {
                        // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
                        if (checkbox.checked) {
                            // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
                            info.draggedEl.parentNode.removeChild(info.draggedEl);
                        }
                    },

                });

                calendar.render();
            });
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
                var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

                var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                    selectable: true,
                    headerToolbar: {
                        left: 'prev,next today',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay',
                    },
                    dateClick: function (info) {
                        alert('clicked ' + info.dateStr);
                    },
                    select: function (info) {
                        alert('selected ' + info.startStr + ' to ' + info.endStr);
                    },
                });

                calendar.render();
            });

            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
                var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

                var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
                    headerToolbar: {
                        center: 'addEventButton',
                    },
                    customButtons: {
                        addEventButton: {
                            text: '이벤트 추가',
                            click: function () {
                                var dateStr = prompt('1. Enter a date in YYYY-MM-DD format');
                                var date = new Date(dateStr + 'T00:00:00'); // will be in local time
                        var nameStr = prompt('2. Enter a name of your event');
                        var name = new String(nameStr);
                        
                                if (!isNaN(date.valueOf())) {
                                    // valid?
                                    calendar.addEvent({
                                        title: name,
                                        start: date,
                                        allDay: true,
                                    });
                                    alert('Great. Now, update your database...');
                                } else {
                                    alert('Invalid date.');
                                }
                            },
                        },
                    },
                    locale: 'ko',
                });

                calendar.render();
            });

        </script>

        <style>
            html,
            body {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                font-family: 'Gugi', cursive;
                font-size: 10px;
            }

            #calendar {
                height:600px;
                width: 100%;
                
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="calendar-container">
            <div id="calendar"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Each event handler creates its own calendar and overwrites a previous existing calendar.

Comment: So I combined it into one. But it doesn't work too.

Comment: Please update the question to show how you combined it then. And mention please if you get anything like console errors, and/or exactly what feature isn't doing what you expected. if you only provide very vague descriptions, and don't show the exact code, then we can't help you.